# Не отрабатывает двойное связывание Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js

делаю список

```
 <div v-for="name,i in namesCol" style="display: inline" class="form-group">
  <label :for="i" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{name.value}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" :id="i" :placeholder="i" v-model="name.save"/>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
axios.get('api.php')
    .then(function (response) {
      self.namesCol = response.data.cols;
      var i = null;
      for (var name in self.namesCol) {              
        if (self.namesCol.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          i = name;
          self.colValues[i] = {};
          self.colValues[i].value = self.namesCol[name];
          self.colValues[i].save = null;
        }
      }
      self.namesCol = self.colValues
      console.log(self.colValues)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert(error)
    })
```

при этом если я изменяю vm.namesCol.postfix.save = 34234 то на странице ничего не изменяется

а если ввести значение в инпут, то в консоли я увижу изменение модели

односторонее привязывание получается, а мне нужно двойное

Answer (score 0):

[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Предостережения](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

для многомерного объекта

```
   Vue.set(vm.namesCol, "id.save", 1000)
```